# what is ngrx createSelector and createFeatureSelector?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I have been reading the code of ngrx example app and find two function calls

1. `createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');`

and

2. `createSelector(selectAuthState,(state: AuthState) => state.status);`

What does this do?

```
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');

export const selectAuthStatusState = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.status
);
```

Answer (score 24):

Its used as an optimization step for store slices selection. For example, if you return some heavy computation result for some store slice, then using  `createSelector` will do memoization which means it will keep track of last input params to selector and if they are the same as current ones, it will return last result immediately instead of repeating computation.

ref: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: i am not sure what examples other than on provided link you would want

Comment: Indeed, the ref you provided does explain it quite succinctly.

Comment: ain't the point that auth can be lazyli loaded? For simply accessing a slice of state without computation i don't see a point in memoization, as only pointers should get passed what should be faster and more memory efficient than cashing the states slice

Comment: @Lex you're right about that. For simple cases where you just return slice of the state you could very well use string selectors. But then you have another issue: code consistency & maintenance. In my opinion its a good practice to choose one approach and stick to it. For me, using `createSelectors` everywhere works good because then i have consistent pattern and if i ever choose to add some computation  on top of pure string selection, there is only one place where i need to touch my code. But i guess that's a personal preference.

Comment: For anyone coming from first search result, I recommend reading this for detailed explanation https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors

Comment: It appears the reference link is now broken. Is there a possibility to fix it?

Comment: The correct link is (at least in January 2021): https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Answer (score 2):

**A little bit of background is in order**

In Ngrx there is only one store. This is a giant global variable that any reducer can affect. In large programs, it'll be hard to reason over. We don't wish this on future maintainers.

**How do we make it easier to reason over?**

It is easier to comprehend if the store is partitioned into different features so that actions, reducers, and state that only pertain to a single feature set, for instance logging in, shopping cart, et c. are maintained in different areas/features.

```
Store
+-------------------------------+  {
|  Auth                         |    "auth": { username: "bob", country: "us" },
|  Cart                         |    "cart": { items: [] }
|  ...                          |  }
+-------------------------------+
```

As you probably already know, `createSelector` is used to select something from the store.

```js
export const selectUserName = createSelector(
  (store: any) => store.auth as Auth, // in real life don't use any, see discussion later
  (auth: Auth) => auth.username)
```

We can simplify this into

```js
const selectAuth = createSelector((store: any) => store.auth)
export const selectUserName = createSelector(selectAuth, auth => auth.username)
```

Further simplifying into

```js
const selectAuth = createFeatureSelector<Auth>('auth')
export const selectUserName = createSelector(selectAuth, auth => auth.username)
```

There is an alternate way to writing this if you *love* rxjs

```js
import { pipe } from 'rxjs'
const selectAuth = createFeatureSelector<Auth>('auth')
export const selectUserName = pipe(selectAuth, auth => auth.username)
```

**Optional - discussion on 'any'**

In highly complex applications, whenever you add another feature, the root (global) store's type changes. This can get unwieldy over time.

```
// define in state.js
type RootState = {
  auth: Auth
  cart: Cart
  // keep adding feature
  // ad infinitum...
}

// define in a auth.selector.js
const selectAuth = createSelector((store: RootState) => store.auth)
```

In this sense, using `createFeatureSelector` is preferred because you don't need to define `RootState` at all.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the selector functions([Pure Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)).

- createFeatureSelector('auth'):  Defining the type of
  state in your case AuthState is interface which consists various
  things according to requirment. (The **createFeatureSelector** is a
  convenience method for returning a top level feature state. It
  returns a typed selector function for a feature slice of state)
- createSelector(selectAuthState,(state: AuthState) => state.status):
  this line is use to select data based upon particular state in this
  case state of type AuthSate and assigning state.status to state along
  with selectAuthState

For better understanding u can refer to ngrx documentation [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)